# data persistence on remote server

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to understand some basic things. I'm a php programmer and I'm interested in flutter. If anyone can answer, I would really appreciate it...

1. I use mysql in my projects, which are on hostgator. I heard that sqlite is only for local storage and in my case the entire web project will be hosted on the remote server. Can I use sqlite to save my customers' data? Or is there something native better? A big concern of mine!
2. Is flutter mature enough for robust commercial applications?
3. Does the documentation indicate when something applies to an earlier version? Or is the information all mixed up and it's up to the programmer to identify when something is only valid for versions prior to flutter 3?

thank you for any guidance

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Sqlite, but I would recommend Firestore/Firebase for stuff like that. It's very easy to implement it and they have great solutions for many thigs.
2. Yes it is! Many commercial applications are running on flutter now. For example the Google Ads app is built with flutter.
3. I don't really know for sure, but I know that the one time I had a problem with it, it was declared.

Comment: 2. would like a free option, similar to mysql

Comment: Firebase/Firestore has a free plan/quota. But yes you could also use every other database - MySQL among them

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd prefer saving user's data on the cloud. I personally like Google's firebase which helps with authentication and storage using RealTime Database. It's pretty easy to sync your user's data into the DB and even stores data using cache in case the user is offline and syncs to DB once device is online. You can find more about firebase and their products [here](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database).
2. Flutter is a really great framework to get your apps done for multiple platforms at once, thanks to its cross platform compatibility! If you don't want to spend time creating app for multiple devices, flutter's the way to go. I personally think flutter web is yet to grow, but it will overtime, afterall, it's opensource framework by Google. I'd suggest this idea 8.5/10
3. Flutter docs are pretty well written and an beginner could get through it with some video examples (included in documentation) as well. In case something you want to use isn't supported in newer version of flutter, the text editor will show a line over the code meaning that it is deprecated and wouldn't be supported. There's always an alternative, which you could find using flutter docs or YouTube. Flutter docs are optimised for beginners 9/10

Comment: the project I have to do is for browser access. "flutter web" would be the right one? Maybe I'm confusing things as English is not my default language (Brazil)

Comment: Yeah no issues, go with flutter, you'll get your work done easily! By flutter web i mean flutter app run on web, i.e chrome or other browsers

Comment: I hope to have that confidence of yours in three months....

Comment: Sure you will! You can test deploy your website using firebase hosting (free). LMK if you face any issues while development, I'd be more than happy to help!

Comment: And if you're learning flutter, I'd really suggest 'Flutter for beginners' by thenetninja on YouTube.

Comment: " if you face any issues while development, I'd be more than happy to help!"

I will remember that for sure, @Delwinn. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1. There is [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)- the official package repository for Dart and Flutter. You can find many interesting packages there. They give you possibilities that the native Flutter doesn't give.
For example [mysql1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1)- driver for MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).